# Is there any way to download and upload file without any server side language

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

User will click on button to download file, once it started then it will abort or cancel after some time interval.  Also I want to upload a file without user intervention. I would like to know whether it is possible with client side scripting (jQuery, Ajax, jQuery-form.js...). 
Can some one suggest whether it is possible using either of these techniques (i.e. without any server side scripting).

Regds

Comment: It's not, you can download a file when the user clicks something with the HTML5 `download` attribute, but you can't upload files unless the user chooses to do so, and you'll need serverside logic to catch the file and do something with it.

Comment: Nope. If there is no server side language, where would the client upload the file to?

Comment: You can make requests to the server with or without files all you want.  Of course, if there's no code on the server to handle the request, then I'm not sure what you expect to happen... And no, there's no way to upload a file without user intervention. I'm sure we're all very thankful of the fact that websites can't arbitrarily scrape files from our local computers.

Comment: some http servers like apache allow webDAV publishing using PUT to upload without tradiational server-side scripts like php handlers.

Comment: WebRTC serverless in a near futur, we hope

Comment: @mituw16 - With an HTTP PUT request, the intended destination is encoded in the URI. While most servers require some sort of server-side script to handle a PUT request (just as they do with a POST request), some servers provide configurations whereby PUT requests are handled without any script.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: not likely. The long answer:

You might be able to upload a file using a PUT http request. However, most servers are not set up to handle PUT requests without some sort of server-side scripting. (See [this article](http://www.apacheweek.com/features/put) for how Apache can be set up to handle PUT requests.) Also, many servers are set up to not handle PUT requests at all due to security concerns.

Another possibility is to store files on the server using ftp. (See the [Mozilla docs on using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).) Unfortunately, most browsers will not support an Ajax request where the protocol is changed to `ftp:`. (Note that the [XMLHttpRequest spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#introduction) states that protocols other than HTTP/HTTPS might be supported but are not covered by the spec.) As with PUT, configuring the server to handle ftp requests also raises security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not, as there are some basic questions that the browser scripting cannot answer, the most important being:

- Where do I save the file to?